# Note: Need to manually update the pg_stats_reporter.ini if have upgraded

Tags: php, linux, postgresql, apache

when i finally finish installation and configuration of pg_stats_reporter

then this quertion occur , how can i fix it

```
Error in pg_stats_reporter.ini
- Connection failure.(repository database = postgres)

Note: Need to manually update the pg_stats_reporter.ini if have upgraded.
```

i alread modified the pg_stats_reporter.ini

```
host = localhost
port = 5432
dbname = postgres
username = postgres
password = postgres
```

and restart the db and httpd

but it didn't work .

best regard .

Answer (score 0):

it seens that pg_hba.conf hadn't been correctly configurated

just add this trust messege

```
host    poprdres      poprdres        127.0.0.1/32            trust
```

to pg_hbaa.conf
and that it goes well.